# How can I save and load the state of a NSDate to a file?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I would like my app to load in the state of a NSDate object when is loaded and be able to save a new state set by a spinner.

My first dea was to get the NSdate object from the spinner then call descriptionWithLocale to get the date as a string, then save this string.  But I could not see any methods to load a date as a string into a NSDAte.

Comment: It conforms to nscoding

Comment: Why not simply store the `NSDate` in `NSUserDefaults`? Using any form of `description` is a terrible way to store the date. The format could change any time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your requirements, you have a couple of options. As Carl and rmaddy pointed out, NSDate conforms to NSCoding, which means it is serializable and can be easily stored in the NSUserDefaults. Here's a nice [tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-working-with-nsuserdefaults--mobile-6039) on using NSUserDefaults.

Alternatively, you can just store the date as an NSTimeInterval. In that case, you can use any of the following methods to store and retrieve the NSDate object (from [NSDate class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html)).

```
+ dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:
+ dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:
– timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate
– timeIntervalSince1970
```

The dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970 and corresponding timeIntervalSince1970 methods are useful if you care about storing the date in epoch time.

Comment: FYI - `NSDate` can be stored as-is in `NSUserDefaults`. It has nothing to do with it conforming to `NSCoding`. It doesn't need to be serialized.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of converting `NSData` to `NSString`, better way is convert to NSTimeInterval (which is `double`) using NSDate `-timeIntervalSince1970` method, then you can sore it in NSUserDefaults if you like.

If you really want save to file you can insert `NSDate` into `NSDictionary` object then save `NSDictionary` with `-writeToFile:atomically:` method (restore with `+dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:`)

Comment: You can store the `NSDate` in `NSUserDefaults` directly. No need to convert to `double` first.

Comment: No. Use timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate

Comment: @rmaddy it's not really a conversion. As I'm sure you know, NSDate is a simple wrapper around that double.

Comment: it is a conversion by copy: the double that is returned lives on the stack, all objects on the heap. there-for it is copied twice: when retrieved from the date from heap to stack and back when it is added as a value to the userdefault.